# How to return database table name in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way that I can get the current database table in use by the model that I'm in? I see that there is a table() function in Laravel/Database/Eloquent/model.php but I've been unsuccessful calling it calling it from the model that I'm in.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

There is a public getTable() method defined in [Eloquent\Model](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getTable) so you should be able to use `$model->getTable()`.

Comment: Well that seems to work only if you have actual instance of the model. It does not work when called as a static function.

Comment: @Robert it's calling an instance method, not a static method, so there's nothing to infer that the static method would exist.

Comment: You don't have to have an instance. You could do `app(Model::class)->getTable();`

Comment: @iSWORD if we want to get Model name from command line how can we call it

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi `Model::class` is just a string. You could pass it in the command line and use the variable. e.g. `app($modelClass)->getTable()`. It has to include the namespace though.

Comment: @iSWORD You DO have to have an instance. You're creating one with `app()`. 

Comment: getTable() does not include any table prefix, if you're using that.

Comment: that's insane, every time I need a string I have to load the whole class...

Answer (score 73):

Taylor has an [answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1436) to your question:

Within the model class you can do something like this:

```
return with(new static)->getTable();
```

If you want all your models to have the ability to return table name statically, then so something like this:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public static function getTableName()
    {
        return with(new static)->getTable();
    }

}

class User extends BaseModel {

}


User::getTableName();
```

Comment: For Laravel 5.3 you have to put that in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

Works fine, thanks!

Comment: Do never do that @Santee. Never ever change the files inside `vendor` folder.

Comment: I see not benefits using `with` here.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Afanasyev it has benefit. I can do it in one-liner inside conroller. See my answer

Comment: @poring91 why is it `with(new static)` better than `(new static)`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-with

Comment: @Yevgeniy Afanasyev I believe this since https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#miscellaneous and somehow missing in some versions, with can be used for method chaining. But, it seems there is update on newer version and when I test it, using ```with(new Class)``` and just ```(new Class)``` gives the same result. Thanks to remind me

Answer (score 21):

**Edit April 2019: This answer is now out of date. See the new correct answer by Flyn San**

Yes - Eloquent has a `$table` variable. There are two ways you can access this:

```
class yourModel extends Eloquent {

        public static $table = "differentTable";

        function someFunction()
        {
             return yourModel::$table;
        }
}
```

**or**

```
class yourModel extends Eloquent {

    public function someFunction()
    {
        return $this->table();

    }
}
```

then in your code

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $model = new yourModel();   
    dd($model->someFunction());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried this with both setting the table name manually and not. I keep on getting "Using $this when not in object context". Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Chris G: can you copy/paste your code here since error you are getting looks like you are calling $this inside a static method

Comment: I would think there is a getTable() function already in the eloquent model.  Aside from that, it makes no sense to copy and paste the same function in children classes.  If a protected property lacks a function wrapper (and in this case it does not) use a trait.

Comment: @JedLynch - this answer was in 2012, long before that function existed in Laravel. I'll edit it to be point out it's an old answer.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, i'm using laravel 5.4

`return (new static)->getTable();`

Comment: works on laravel 5.2 as well

Comment: Works on Laravel 5.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

It will return the table name from the model. perfectly worked on laravel 8

```
app(Modelname::class)->getTable()
```

you have to replace Modelname with your model class

Comment: works on laravel 10

Answer (score 6):

Since `table` is a protected property in the Model class (Laravel >= 5) you will need an instance of your Model.

Here is a case example:

```
        DB::table( (new YourModelClassname)->getTable() )
            ->update(['field' => false]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get name of a model's table by following code:

If we have a Model as ModelName:

```
ModelName::query()->getQuery()->from
```

This method also works fine in case of custom table name that are defined by `protected $table = 'custom_table_name'` in the Model.

Comment: `User::query()->from`

Answer (score 5):

Based on [Lucky Soni answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24477971/1940489), there is another easy trick if you want to directly call it from **Vontroller** or **View**.

Tested in Laravel 6, and I keep using it, if you are **"One Line Programmer"** who hates extra line instance declaration. No need for extra lines in Model file too.

```
$string_table_name = with(new \App\Model\TableModelName)->getTable();
```

or better you may also be able to just call this

```
$string_table_name = (new \App\Model\TableModelName)->getTable();
```

It will return plain string of the tabel name even if you rename `$table` variable inside model class.

**EDIT :**

Minus Rep ?? Maybe you should try this first in your **controller** instead making new function in model class just to get table name and no need to declare the object when calling.

`with()` itself is Laravel helper function that returns an object of the class. and inside class that extends Model, already has function `getTable()`. So, you don't have to put another new redundant function inside model class.
It seems the latest version, you can just call `(new Class)` without `with()` function.

The difference between this answer and Lucky's answer, mine doesn't make any new function inside Model class to get the table name, even you can just call the function inside the Controller and View without declaring the object of model class. It's for beautify the code.

While Lucky's answer create new function that inside Model class, and you need to call the function from the object.

Comment: This seems more "Lucky Soni's answer" as opposed to "based on Lucky Soni's answer". As pointed out on his answer, what is `with()` being used for here?

Comment: wow... -1 ? Lucky Sony put the code inside model. But my way can be just put inside controller only without adding codes inside Model class. That's the difference with more efficient line. ```with()``` is Laravel function that returns object. And getTable is predefined function inside Model class.

Comment: `with()` allows for chaining if not otherwise possible but isn't required if the methods already return their own class instance. I'd say the -1 is because this is more of a comment than an answer? I've had the same thing happen, frustrating but it's how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 4):

Simple way to get table name from Laravel Model by this:

```
$tableName = app(\App\User::class)->getTable();
```

Don't forget to replace:

> \App\User

With Model path.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an other approach so that you can get a model's table name statically.

1. Define a Trait: `app/Traits/CanGetTableNameStatically.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Traits;

trait CanGetTableNameStatically
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return (new static)->getTable();
    }
}
```

2. Extend your required `Model` or `BaseModel` with the `use` statement.

`app/Models/BaseModel.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\CanGetTableNameStatically;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    use CanGetTableNameStatically;

    // ...
}
```

On your models, if you set the custom table name on Laravel's reserved attribute: `protected $table` then it will still work & return correct table name.

`app/Models/Customer.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Master;

use App\Models\BaseModel;

class Customer extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'my_customers';

    // ...
}
```

**Usage**: just call `YourModel::tableName()` anywhere.

In Views:

```
{{ \App\Models\Customer::tableName() }}
```

When doing Joins:

```
DB::table( Product::tableName() . ' AS p' )
->leftJoin( ProductCategory::tableName() . ' AS pc', 'pc.id', '=', 'p.category_id')
// ... etc
```

Note:
I use this approach where needed but full disclosure, I found another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613885/4311336) that have the exact same approach, so I copy pasted here for reference of course with citation thanks to [@topher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2695256/topher)

Answer (score 2):

Based on tailor Otwell's [answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1436#issuecomment-18618393) you could use something like this:

```
with(new Model)->getTable();
```

Note: tested on versions 5.x, 6.x, 7.x, 8.x and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

another solution is to use the `resolve` helper like so:

```php
resolve('\\App\\Models\\User')->getTable()
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers so far will get you the table name with the prefix, if you are using a table name prefix. At this time it seems like we need to concatenate the prefix with the table name ourselves if we want the real name of database table.

Here's how to get the table name including the table prefix:

```php
echo \App\MyModel::query()->getQuery()->getGrammar()->getTablePrefix() . app(\App\MyModel::class)->getTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 7.x (i'm used)
you can get table name with (new Target())->getTable();

```
$query->where('parent_id', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->select('id')->from((new Target())->getTable())->where('unit_id', $request->unit_id);
});
```

hope it's helps

Answer (score 0):

To people who want to get table name from a `Builder` object instead of other object, here you are:

```
$conn = DB::connection("my_private_mysql_conn");
$my_builder_object = $conn->table("my_table_name");

//This will print out the table name
print $my_builder_object->from;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will  work 100%. You will get table name.

```
    $object = new OrderStockProduct();
    // Use below line only when you have dynamic connection in laravel project
   // $object->setConnection('mysql');
    $object = $object->getTable();
    dd($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some syntactic sugar if you do not wish to do something like `(new User)->getTable()`.

1. Create and attach the following macro to `EloquentBuilder`.

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as EloquentBuilder;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...

    public function boot()
    {
        EloquentBuilder::macro('table', fn() => $this->model->getTable());
        // EloquentBuilder::macro('table', fn() => $this->from);
    }
}
```

2. Call the `table` method statically on any Model:

```php
App\Models\User::table();
// users
```

Answer (score -3):

I just wanted to add the following for people coming from search engines:

In case you do not even want to instantiate the Model at all (faster?) :

```
$model = 'App\User';
$modelTable = str_replace('\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($model))));
dd($modelTable); // will return "users"
```

That might look ugly but that's exactly how the getTable() method resolves it under the hood, so...

You will need to `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` on top of your file.

Addendum: implying you follow the framework's standards (i.e: `Post` model has `posts` table, User model has `users` table, etc)

Comment: This works as long as you are not overwriting the table variable to use a different table in the model.

Comment: I'd say this is definitely not the correct way to go about it. Assuming too much based on the model's class name is very likely to run into issues. And as pointed out by Ludwig, won't work if you're overwriting the table variable.

Comment: You both seem to ignore the addendum.

Answer (score -4):

In **Laravel 4** use **static** method

```
$table_name = Model::getTable();
```

or "**self**" inside Eloquent Model

```
$table_name = self::getTable();
```

Comment: It seems that the getTable() function is not static - you need an instance of the model to get the table:
`$model = new Model();
$table_name = $model->getTable();` (I'm using Laravel 4.1.30).

Comment: as of 16/01/2017 I was actually able to get table's name inside the model via `self::getTable()`. Laravel 5.5.