# Getting table name using Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
class SampleELoq extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function conditionFields() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\EloquentModel\ConditionField');
    }
}
```

nameSpace  is the name space of the SampleELoq

```
$Eloq = $nameSpace::find(1);

$table = with(new $nameSpace->conditionFields)->getTable();

print_r(Schema::getColumnListing($table));
```

How can i able to get the table name of the conditionFields?

Comment: getTable should return table name. What are you getting in $table?

Answer (score 5):

To get table from conditionFields you need return relation model, then you can get table by getTable method.
Some like this

```
Model::first()->conditionFields()->getRelated()->getTable()
```

Comment: This causes the first model to be loaded from the database, which is unnecessary  and can cause an error for empty tables.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to retrieve a model from the database like in [Catain Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8778989/captain-fail)'s answer: you can obtain the related table name in any situation as follows:

```php
$relation = (new MyModel)->myRelationship(); // Returns a Relations subclass like BelongsTo or HasOne.
$relatedModel = $relation->getRelated(); // Returns a new empty Model
$tableName = $relatedModel->getTable();
```

Or in short:

```php
$tableName = (new MyModel)->myRelationship()->getRelated()->getTable();
```

Comment: This one worked! Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20812314/5113030 (*How to return database table name in Laravel*...)

Answer (score 1):

After digging hard I found a solution. It can be achieved like this.

```
$tableName = (new SampleELoq)->conditionFields()->getTable();
```

**In General**

```
$tableName = (new MODELCLASS)->RELATIONSHIP()->getTable();
```

Comment: This is incorrect and leads to the following error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo::getTable()`

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways :-

```
     dd(Model::$table);
```

or inside your model :-

```
 dd($this->table());
```