# How can you change the table where you users are called from in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm pretty new to Laravel and PHP but I have made an app that requires a user to log in, now this table is called `users` and all my users sit in there, but I want to make another table called `temUsers` and use that table instead...  but I don't know where the code points to that user table so I can change it to `temUsers`. Can anyone please assist in knowing which file would point to this?.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$table`  property in `User` model.

```
 protected $table="temUsers";
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

Comment: would adding this line overwrite it from reading off the users table?

Comment: @segawe.yes it wil overwrite.after adding this line user model read data from temUsers

Comment: What about other pages calling the table?

Comment: @if you have used table name in query then you have no option i guess.but you can refactor yuor code by using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082682/how-to-return-database-table-name-in-laravel/24477971

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` `   .....I get this error

Comment: do you have email column in temUsers table

Comment: yes I do, all the columns on the users match the new table

Comment: @segawe.then it should work.try clearing cache

Comment: this program is hosted on a server though...how would I clear cache from there