# General error: 1 no such table: App\Models\ModelName while testing laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

My test:

```
class FloorStackTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker, DatabaseMigrations;
    protected $endPoint = '/endpoint';

    public function test_unit_type_note_added_successfully()
    {
        $this->signIn();
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $unitType = UnitType::factory()->create();
        $note = $this->faker()->sentence(3);
        $resp = $this->ajaxPost($this->admin_route.$this->endPoint."/".$unitType->property_version_id."/save-ut-note",[
            'notes' => [
                [
                    "ut_note_id" => "utn_".$unitType->id,
                    "note" => $note
                ]
            ]
        ])->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
        $results = [
            'notes'         => $note
        ];


        //i could print upto here
        dd('hit');

        $this->assertDatabaseHas(UnitType::class,$results);

        //but could not print here
        dd('hit');
        
    }
}
```

I am using `sqlite` for testing and I am using laravel 8 (which was previously updated from laravel 5, just in case to confirm)

I the above code, you can see the point upto where I could `print hit`.

I am using `.env.testing`

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE="database/test.sqlite"
DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=false
```

I have already been using: `use RefreshDatabase` but still it is showing error. and the full error is:

```
Tests\Feature\FloorStackTest::test_unit_type_note_added_successfully
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: App\Models\UnitType (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "App\Models\UnitType" where ("notes" = Eveniet incidunt consequuntur dolore est.))
```

And my model `UnitType` has this

```
    use SoftDeletes, HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'unit_types';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at','deleted_at'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that passing a Model, or fully qualified class name, to the [`assertDatabaseHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#assert-database-has) method is only available starting in version 8 of the framework. See the signature change below:

[Signature in v7](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.html#method_assertDatabaseHas): `protected $this assertDatabaseHas(string $table, array $data, string|null $connection = null)`.

[Signature in v8](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.html#method_assertDatabaseHas): `protected $this assertDatabaseHas(Model|string $table, array $data, string|null $connection = null)`.

Ultimately, the assertion has to be made using the actual table name. This is how it is demonstrated in the docs:

```php
$this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
    'email' => 'sally@example.com',
]);
```

So if you're using Laravel <8, you could to pass the table name string to get the desired results:

```php
$this->assertDatabaseHas('unit_types', $results);
```

As an alternative, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082682/how-to-return-database-table-name-in-laravel), you could still use the model class to get the table name instead of hard-coding the string.

Something like this:

```php
$this->assertDatabaseHas((new UnitType)->getTable(), $results);
```

In Laravel 8, the method will take a model, and run it through this method to get the table name:

```php
protected function getTable($table)
{
    return is_subclass_of($table, Model::class) ? (new $table)->getTable() : $table;
}
```

Here `table` can be a model instance, or the fully qualified class name (`new UnitType`, or `UnitType::class`). Just note that it has to extend the base `Model` class in order for Laravel to parse it correctly, otherwise it will just pass along the class name string to the query.

Comment: I am not sure about that, because on another project I have been using `Model::class` and its running fine.

Comment: Does `UnitType` extend `Model`? It does look like there's undocumented functionality for passing the model, I'll update my answer to include it, but you should probably update your question to include more of the model code.

Comment: I got it, looks like it is facing the same table issue despite being the laravel 8, it is not accepting class model but working with 'table name'. May be it wasn't properly updated, but now I am facing this new issue: `General error: 1 no such table: migrations (SQL: select max("batch") as aggregate from "migrations")`

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but you probably shouldn't be using both `RefreshDatabase` and `DatabaseMigrations` traits in your test. They accomplish the same thing and may be conflicting with each other. `RefreshDatabase` is the preferable one most times, since it will determine if it needs to run migrations or only rollback transactions.